# How do you write a Functor on a data type that uses concrete types?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to get into Haskell from the world of GO, so am almost certainly missing something trivial but this has me stumped!

The following compiles but does nothing useful.

```
data Thing a = Type1 Int | Type2 Int Int deriving Show

instance Functor Thing where
    fmap func (Type1 a) = Type1 a
    fmap func (Type2 a b) = Type2 a b
```

As soon as I try to actually use the "func", it wont compile. For example, just using "func" in the first of the two pattern rules like this..

```
data Thing a = Type1 Int | Type2 Int Int deriving Show

instance Functor Thing where
    fmap func (Type1 a) = Type1 (func a)
    fmap func (Type2 a b) = Type2 a b
```

Gives the following error but if I declare "Thing" using "Type1 a | Type2 a a" then it compiles ok.

```
x2.hs:4:34:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Thing a -> Thing b
          at x2.hs:4:5
    Relevant bindings include
      func :: a -> b (bound at x2.hs:4:10)
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> Thing a -> Thing b (bound at x2.hs:4:5)
    In the first argument of ‘Type1’, namely ‘(func a)’
    In the expression: Type1 (func a)

x2.hs:4:39:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Thing a -> Thing b
          at x2.hs:4:5
    Relevant bindings include
      func :: a -> b (bound at x2.hs:4:10)
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> Thing a -> Thing b (bound at x2.hs:4:5)
    In the first argument of ‘func’, namely ‘a’
    In the first argument of ‘Type1’, namely ‘(func a)’
```

Can anyone explain why and what I can do to fix it? Is it possible to use concrete types in a data definition and then use that in a Functor or are we limited to using generic type variables (excuse me if I'm using the wrong words here)?

Comment: `fmap` has to work with *any* function you  pass as an argument, but your definition only works for functions of type `Int -> Int`. `Thing` has the right *kind* to be a functor, but that's not sufficient.

Comment: `data Thing a = ...` usually means the `a` appears on RHS. That's what `Functor/fmap` is expecting.

Comment: Wow! that was quick - thanks.

So, do I have this right.. by implication the data type for a Functor (Thing in this case) can only use "generic" types (is that the right word) ie: I cant be specific about the types of data embedded in it's "container" types (Type1 and Type2 in this case). Or is there another way to do it? Otherwise it seems like we loose the tight type control that Haskell is famous for in this kind of use case.

Comment: There is a `mono-traversable` package that lets you make something like `data Thing = Type1 Int | Type2 Int Int` into a functor-like thing, allowing `omap foo (Type1 x)` and `omap foo (Type2 x y)`, where you'll get a type error only if `foo` doesn't have type `Int -> Int`.

Comment: In `Thing a`, `a` is a [phantom type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type).

Comment: The whole **point** of making some type `F` a `Functor` is that you can `fmap` any function of any type `a -> b`, and the resulting function will take `F a` to `F b`. That means in the `Functor F` instance definition, you're only going to be applying the mapped function to the `a` values that are inside `F`, not any other values. If you want to do something else, that's not bad or wrong, it just has nothing to do with `Functor` and `fmap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use concrete types in a data definition and then use that in a Functor or are we limited to using generic type variables (excuse me if I'm using the wrong words here)?

You are not limited. However, only fields whose type is (or mentions) the last generic variable in the data declaration will be able to be modified in your `Functor` instance. (Some modifications to fields with other types are allowed by the type-checker; but all will cause the functor laws to be violated.) So, for example, this has a mix of generic and concrete fields:

```
data Thing a = Type1 Int a | Type2 Int Int

instance Functor Thing where
    fmap f (Type1 n a) = Type1 n (f a)
    fmap f (Type2 m n) = Type2 m n
```

Of course, there is nothing stopping you from writing another function, not named `fmap`, that does whatever you like. So, this is also fine:

```
data Thing = Type1 Int | Type2 Int Int

notFmap :: (Int -> Int) -> Thing -> Thing
notFmap f (Type1 n) = Type1 (f n)
notFmap f (Type2 m n) = Type2 m n
```